# No template found for module - Prestashop

Tags: php, templates, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So I have created my first custom module and I have a problem regarding the displaying of the template. I have followed the tutorial(more or less) from here but when I am enabling my module it shows that "No template found for module ". My module name is kamailchimp so inside the folder of the module i have the kamailchimp.php with the following code

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}


class Kamailchimp extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'kamailchimp';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Kon Ang';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array(
            'min' => '1.7.0.0',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_,
        );
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('KA - Embedded Mailchimp Form');
        $this->description = $this->l('This module will allow you to display your embedded mailchimp form');

        $this->templateFile = 'module:kamailchimp/views/templates/hook/kamailchimp.tpl';
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayHome');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
    public function hookDisplayHome($params)
    {
      return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->templateFile);
    }
}
```

and my kamailchimp.tpl file is inside modules/kamailchimp/views/templates/hook folder and in themes/PRS025/modules/kamailchimp/views/templates/hook as well.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ? 
PS 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two ways of calling a template.
You can either do it like this:

```
public function hookDisplayHome($params)
{
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/kamailchimp.tpl');
}
```

or like this:

```
public function hookDisplayHome($params)
{
    return $this->fetch('module:kamailchimp/views/templates/hook/kamailchimp.tpl');
    // return $this->fetch($this->templateFile); // Or like this as you set $this->templateFile at the beginning of your file
}
```

I recommend you do it this last way, as this is the new and better way to do it in PrestaShop 1.7

Comment: Hey ébewè, I tried all your ways and I get a "
ContextErrorException in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 47:
Notice: Undefined index: value"

Comment: Can you add the code of your `kamailchimp.tpl` file ?

Comment: I just have a `<h1>Hello World</h1>` in the tpl nothing more

Comment: Ok I found my mistake. I was doing the changes on modules/kamailchimp/views/templates/hook/kamailchimp.tpl but I had a also on my theme on themes/THEME/modules/modules/kamailchimp/views/templates/hook/kamailchimp.tpl that I have forgotten to delete a value.

Comment: Glad you found the solution ;)

Comment: You were the reason that I found it ! I was stuck on a loop :P 
So thank you!

Comment: Surely it should work, but it silently fails in my case